# Loop Through Two Dataframe Columns to Create Key-Value Pairs For Value Dictionaries Nested Inside A Dictionary Nested Inside Another Dictonary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested, key-value

I want to create a metadata variable based on my input dataset's columns using dictionaries.  Specifically, I want the metadata variable to have exactly this structure and values:

```
metadata = {
    'fields': {
        'id': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'name': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'category_id': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'category_label': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'Compatible operating systems.2507': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'Compatible operating systems.2507.unit': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'Dimensions (WxDxH).49': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'Dimensions (WxDxH).49.unit': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'Internal mass storage.588': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'Internal mass storage.588.unit': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'Processor cores.6089': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'Processor cores.6089.unit': {'type': 'categorical'},
        'Built-in processor.7787': {'type': 'boolean'},
        'Built-in processor.7787.unit': {'type': 'categorical'}
    },
    'constraints': [],
    'primary_key': 'id'
}
```

My input dataframe to create the above metadata structure looks like below:

[image]

So far I have attempted the following code to do this:

```
metadata = {}

metadata['fields'] = {}

for col_name in table_dtypes['index']:
    metadata['fields'][col_name] = {}
```

The code above outputs this:

[image]

As you can see, my values are {}.  I want to fill them in with 'type' as the key and the associated value will be column "0" in my screen shot dataframe (i.e. object, boolean).  I want this to be an automated looping process because in the future I will have 'float', 'integer' and other data types in addition to 'categorical'.

How do I go about doing this?

**Update:**

```
series_structure = pd.Series()

for i in table_dtypes[0]:
    if i == "object":
        type_dict = {'type': 'categorical'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
    elif i == "boolean":
        type_dict = {'type': 'boolean'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
    elif i == "datetime64": # revisit here 
        type_dict = {'type': 'datetime', 'format': '%Y-%m-%d'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
    elif i == "int64":
        type_dict = {'type': 'id', 'subtype': 'integer'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict)
    elif i == "float64": # revisit here 
        type_dict = {'type': 'numerical', 'subtype': 'float'}
        series_structure.append(type_dict, ignore_index=ignore_index, verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `0` column into an array of dicts, using `replace` to replace `'object'` with `'categorical'` (and any others you might need)) and then applying a function to return a dict with `type` as the key and that value. You can then `zip` that to the `index` column and convert to a dict of fields. Finally you can add that to an output dict with the `constraints` and `primary_id` properties.

```py
types = df['0'].replace({ 'object' : 'categorical' }).apply(lambda x:{ 'type' : x })
fields = dict(zip(df['index'], types))
metadata = { 'fields' : fields, 
             'constraints': [],
             'primary_key': df.loc[0, 'index']
           }
```

Note I've assumed the `primary_key` is stored in the first row of `index`, if that is not the case, you can adjust as required.

For this sample input:

```
                     index        0
0                       id   object
1                     name   object
2              category_id   object
3           category_label   object
4  Built-in processor.7787  boolean
5                  A float    float
6               An integer      int
```

You will get this output (dumped as JSON for readability):

```
{
    "fields": {
        "id": {
            "type": "categorical"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "categorical"
        },
        "category_id": {
            "type": "categorical"
        },
        "category_label": {
            "type": "categorical"
        },
        "Built-in processor.7787": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "A float": {
            "type": "float"
        },
        "An integer": {
            "type": "int"
        }
    },
    "constraints": [],
    "primary_key": "id"
}
```

Comment: this is brilliant!  thank you ... never thought to use lambda and zip in that way but makes so much sense

Comment: I just ran into an issue and hoping to pick your brain.  How do I account for cases where the metadata has to look like this ... 

'experience_years': {'type': 'numerical', 'subtype': 'integer'} or start_date': {'type': 'datetime', 'format': '%Y-%m-%d'},

Comment: @PineNuts0 I'd replace my lambda function with an actual function that looked at the `type` value and then returned the appropriate dict. You could do it with a simple lookup e.g. `types = { 'int' : { 'type': 'numerical', 'subtype':'integer' }, 'date' : {'type': 'datetime', 'format': '%Y-%m-%d'}, 'boolean' : { 'type': 'boolean' }, ...}` and then your function is just `def get_type(type): return types[type]`. Actually I guess you could still write that as a lambda if you make `types` global.

Comment: please see my update in my original post.  I tried to recreate your "types" variable with conditional if statements but it didn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @PineNuts0 that was probably worthy of another question. Anyway, it can be simpler than I suggested. See https://ideone.com/nCQt4D

Comment: thank you!!!  next time, I'll be sure to make it another question.  really appreciate you!

Comment: @PineNuts0 actually, sorry, I see you did write another question, it has pretty much exactly the same answer but without the combining to the final dict.